Treesitter uv_dlopen: no_error after :TSInstall
I wanted to try NvChad as I've been trying to handroll my own config, but it is taking longer than expected, and so I want to gap that difference. I installed it on WSL ubuntu 24.04 (since I want to use it at work) and almost instantly, treesitter broke. Now, I have ran into treesitter issues before, but I've managed to solve them/find solutions since the error had some info. But this time, I get an error for every parser, that is not loaded from the built in ones in nvim. So c is fine and few others, howerver lua, luadoc, printf, vim, vimdoc, and any other I install with :TSInstall like odin doesn't work.
I tried :TSUpdate, :TSUninstall all, Lazy sync, MasonInstallAll. I've tried reinstalling Nvim and NvChad. My config is completely stock, except shorter timeoutlen=50 and a recipe from NvChad to correct the " and + registers
Full error from :checkhealth
- ERROR lua(highlights): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/lua/highlights.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(locals): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/lua/locals.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(folds): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/lua/folds.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(indents): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/lua/indents.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(injections): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/lua/injections.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR luadoc(highlights): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'luadoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  luadoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/luadoc/highlights.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'luadoc': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR printf(highlights): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'printf': uv_dlopen: no error
  printf(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/printf/highlights.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'printf': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(highlights): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vim/highlights.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(locals): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vim/locals.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(folds): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vim/folds.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(injections): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vim/injections.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(highlights): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vimdoc/highlights.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(injections): ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/home/pholub/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/queries/vimdoc/injections.scm", failed to load: ...nux64/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error

I have no idea where to even begin with uv_dlopen: no error as I've never seen it and haven't been able to find anything about it. If someone knows from where this issue stems, any help would be great.

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Do you mean TreeSitter? I don't know what the issue tracker would be in that case. When I try to search for any kind of issue trackers in TreeSitter or other plugins, only github issues come up. Do you mean that? If yes, I have looked at a bunch of issues, and none were like mine, nor did the fixes work.

Yes, that's an issue tracker. Where you look at existing issues… and open new ones.

I've been sitting on this and trying out other options. Unfortunately I can't open a new issue as it requires reproduction steps and the issue is unique to my work laptop on which I can't do proper steps to reproduce/troubleshoot (reinstall clean wsl).
